# Migrating data from SQLite3 to Postgresql using DBeaver

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, dbeaver

My project use an SQLite3 DB but now I need to do a migration from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL. I've used DBeaver for do this using the "Import Data" option. At the end of the importation of all the tables from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL I noticed this error when I try to add a new content:

> IntegrityError at /engine/kernel/keyconcept/add/
>
> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "kernel_keyconcept_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) already exists.

If I add a new model, into this project, that use the new DB(PostgreSQL) there aren't problems to add contents, but if I use the old models I see the *IntegrityError* above.

I've do a test with a model that have only two rows: with the first attempt I received a same error but for key id 1, with the second attempt I received a same error but for key id 2. When I've tried for the third time I was be able to add the content and the same think happens for the next attempts.

So I think that the row counter of the every tables after the migrations never start from the last content but from zero. It strange because previous I've do the same migrations but from SQLite3 to SQLite3 whitout problems.

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved using [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) and [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) instead of DBeaver and following [this examples](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata) all work fine.

In my case I need to exclude some apps as auth and contenttypes, then with dumpdata I've used this:

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes --exclude auth --indent 2 > db.json
```

To upload tha datas I've used this:

```
python3 manage.py loaddata db.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the sequences used to generate primary keys. There is a management command that prints the necessary SQL: [sqlsequencereset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset)

Note that it only prints out the SQL, you have to execute it manually (which you can probably do with DBeaver).

Comment: I've used this but nothing is changed. One of my apps in INSTALLED_APP is "about", I've writed `django-admin sqlsequencereset about` and I see this error message: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting STATIC_URL, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: If I use `python3 manage.py sqlsequencereset about` I see this: `BEGIN;
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"about_eventchoice"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "about_eventchoice";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"about_attivita"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "about_attivita";
COMMIT;` but I see again the `IntegrityError` when I try to add the contents. This happen for all the apps.

Comment: The `sqlsequencereset` command only prints the SQL. You have to manually execute it, e.g. with a graphical tool like DBeaver or `python3 manage.py dbshell`

Comment: It is not clear for me how I can do this, I think that it depends on the fact that I'm newbie. But I've solved using dumpdata/loaddata. Now I put the answer on my question. Thank you for your support